# Why won't Age of Empires 3 work?

Tags: wine

I copied my 3 cds into one directory and ran the installer from there with Wine.  It installed perfectly fine.  I was even able to watch the intro, navigate all the menus and start a game.  However, about 1-30 seconds after starting the game, I get the infamous "Age of Empires 3 has encountered a problem and needs to close" pop-up with the "send/don't send" buttons.  I was unable to determine any error from that.

I ran it from a terminal and I believe the important part of the output is:

```
err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"age3.exe"
err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"4.105.919.3236"
err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"deformerdll.dll"
err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"0.0.0.0"
err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"00001363"
```

Can someone tell me what this means and what I need to do to get AoE3 working?

I looked on the cd for deformerdll.dll and also checked Winetricks for it.  I didn't find it.

*Note:* I have already tried the methods suggested at [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3795&iTestingId=64297) and it still doesn't work.

For anyone interested in the whole several page output of terminal, [here it is](http://pastebin.com/6uCrtU8Z).

Comment: I think the wine mailing list is more appropriate than the askubuntu page - there are more people who know about wine than here.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at [Codeweavers: Crossover Games](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxgames/) I've a friend who uses it and says it runs games such as World of Warcraft flawlessly, and others like The Witcher etc. I know this isn't really an answer but just thought you might be able to give it a shot? Hope it helps you somehow!

Comment: @zkr Well, my budget is zero.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  PlayOnLinux worked for me.

Comment: @cwe I will keep that in mind for any more questions I may have.

Comment: No worries @John just thought I'd suggest it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best chance to install this is using [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) [image: Install PoL] as it'll configure wine to work with Age Of Empires III (and the various expansions) for you.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the [WineAppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3795&iTestingId=14831). I believe this addresses your problem, no?

Comment: Um, no.  Been there, done that.  About 3 times.  And the method that's guaranteed to work?  I followed the link, and they didn't have that wine version anymore.

Comment: Well, I tried, sir. You can always try to downgrade your wine version via terminal.