# What games like Age of Empires and Rise of Nations can I play on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I used to play

1. Age of Empires 2
2. Age of Empires 3
3. Rise of Nations

in Windows 7.

But I find none of them work for me, and I couldn't find any alternatives in the Software Center. Are there any good alternatives for Ubuntu?

Comment: See here for the wine method: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4403&iTestingId=46212 http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=762 Not alot of it is platinum.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53144/why-wont-age-of-empires-3-work

Comment: Search for the game Warzone... I was also playing these 3 games in windows and I loved Warzone since migrate to Ubuntu!

Comment: Another one is unknown-horizons.

Answer (score 4):

You need something like Wine to play the games you mention. How about some new games in the same category that you can get for free?

I can suggest two open-source games in the real-time strategy warfare game category:

- [0 A.D.](http://play0ad.com/) (very similar to Caesar III) – now even in the [Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/0ad/)
- [OpenRA](http://openra.res0l.net/) (Red Alert clone)

Comment: Wine for both game has 'silver' as best so that is probably not going to get him working games ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind 0 A.D exist for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. Check the website he has linked.

Comment: Sorry @alvar I meant the games TS mentioned not ayoun's.

Comment: @Aeyoun Probably should mention that `0 A.D` is still in **Alpha** stage. So don't expect it to be perfect.